# Azure Kubernetes Services Cluster with mutilple nodes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

Currently I have one requirement that :

Let's say I have 2 applications **A** & **B** where **A** talks to **B**. I want to deploy them on **Azure Kubernetes Service** clusters with 5 nodes each having a `Pod` with container containing one instance of the application.

So 2 Clusters, say **ClusterA** and **ClusterB**

**ClusterA** has nodes N1, N2, N3, N4, N5

**ClusterB** has nodes N6, N7, n8, N9 and N10.

I have 2 sets of users **U1** and **U2** . I want to logically partition my clusters such that request from

```
U1 - https -> clusterA( N1, N2, N3) -- HTTP(Rest) -> Cluster B(N6, N7,N8)
U2 - https -> clusterA( N4, N5) -- HTTP(Rest) -> Cluster B(N9, N10)
```

What is the right way to do it if we want to have maximum control on the 2 separate partitions without impacting each other ?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot deploy everything on just one kubernetes cluster and use [NetworkPolicies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) to enforce the required rules by defining which sets of Pods can communicate with another sets of Pods ? It would be much simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0):

InternalLoadBalancer is the right decision for this. 
Seperate Clusters, talking with each other with ingress
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-internal-ip
If you need some compliance you should consider hub-spoke arch.